# Marketing Cloud Trigger Send Bulkify

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am using Marketing Cloud Trigger send on Lead Object.
I have created logic when leads FieldA='Something' then trigger this and send email.

```
trigger Trig_Lead on Lead (after insert, after update) { et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate('Lead');
```

}

As you know

> Triggered sends do not support bulk updates/inserts.

We have data automation which loads data in bulk daily into salesforce Lead object and this trigger send causing problem and make automation fail.

What is best way to bulkify this to avoid this error.

Comment: Is it an option to reduce batch size to 1?

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, Marketing Cloud doesn't support Bulk Updates. You can reach out to Salesforce Account Executive to ask when this will be available to help you decide on your solution options.

Since you're using importing data into Salesforce, you don't need Triggered Send. A Triggered Send is necessary when you want to respond to a user action on Salesforce to send an acknowledgement email.

In your scenario, you can utilize Automation Studio and Journey Builder to create audiences. Since the data is loaded once a day, you can schedule the jobs in Automation Studio and be able to send to all new leads.